# Visual Studio For Mac - How to populate PATH from terminal source?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

**Visual Studio For Mac 8.7.4 (build 38)** - netcore 3.1

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to have **Visual Studio for Mac** utilize the `PATH` set from `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile`?

**CONTEXT:**

I'm having difficulty understanding why `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` in **Visual Studio for Mac** (Fresh Install) returns the following for the `PATH` entry:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources:/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/usr/local/share/dotnet/"
```

But when I debug the same unit test in the same project from JetBrains Rider (Fresh Install) the code below outputs `PATH` contents from my Terminal.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NunitTesting
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void EnvironmentTest()
        {
            var envVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            Console.WriteLine(envVariables);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you probably shouldn't be using non-deterministic data in unit-tests, such as environment-variables. If you do want to include those in your tests then you should validate them prior to the test-proper running, e.g. as a Text Fixture in xUnit.

Comment: Understandable. I'm utilizing Appium's AppiumLocalService which looks up `node`, `java`, and `adb` installations utilizing `PATH`. I found that the framework fails when executing on `Visual Studio for Mac` because `PATH` isn't populated as I would have expected.

Comment: In that case, you should store those paths in a test-configuration-file and then set your test-host process' `PATH` on startup using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` prior to `AppiumLocalService` starting.

Comment: [Visual Studio Dev Community Post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/376446/view.html) - The VS for Mac `PATH` is initially populated from Xamarin during install (some) coming from `/etc/paths.d`. I looked at my `/etc/paths.d`, and found a few entries that contain entries in the path in OP.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio for Mac will not run your Bash profile or your zsh profile so any environment variables defined there will not be used.

Your options are:

1. Run Visual Studio for Mac from your Bash or zsh terminal.

   open -n "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"

Running it from the terminal will cause Visual Studio for Mac to inherit the environment variables defined in the terminal.

However this is not ideal since you cannot run Visual Studio from the Dock or with Finder. Another option is to use a launch agent.

2. Create a launch agent.

Create a .plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` e.g. environment.plist.

Use launchctl in the .plist file to amend the PATH environment variable.

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd”>
<plist version=“1.0”>
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>my.startup</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>sh</string>
<string>-c</string>
<string>launchctl setenv PATH /Volumes/YourDrive/YourPath</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications

Answer (score 1):

> I'm utilizing Appium's AppiumLocalService which looks up `node`, `java`, and `adb` installations utilizing `PATH`. I found that the framework fails when executing on Visual Studio for Mac because `PATH` isn't populated as I would have expected.

In that case, you should store those paths in a test-configuration-file and then set your test-host process' PATH on startup using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` prior to AppiumLocalService starting.

In NUnit, use `OneTimeSetUp` to do this. Please read these documentation pages:

- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/setup-teardown/index.html
- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimesetup.html

```
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Tests;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class VizionzSetUp
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // Load `PATH` files from a configuration file in your project:

        Dictionary<String,String> configFileEntries = ...

        foreach( var kvp in configFileEntries )
        {
            String envVarName  = kvp.Key;
            String envVarValue = kvp.Value;

            // Special-case for PATH where it will concatenate rather than replace:
            if( envVarName == "PATH" )
            {
                envVarValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "PATH" ) + ":" + envVarValue;
            }

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable( envVarName, envVarValue );
        }

        // Now start Appium:

        AppiumLocalService service = AppiumLocalService.BuildDefaultService();
        service.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution, thank you for putting it together. However, I'd like to know if there is a way for `Visual Studio for Mac` to automatically use `PATH` from `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile`. Up-Vote from me.

Comment: @Vizionz No, I don't believe there is, sorry.